# What does "~Method" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I came across some code today that reads

```
public class SomeClass
{
      int DEFAULT_INT = 5;

      public static int SomeMethod()
      {
           return ~FooBar(DEFAULT_INT);
      }

      public static int SomeMethod(int i)
      {
           return ~FooBar(i);
      }

      public static int FooBar(i)
      {
          ......
      }
}
```

I have not seen this before and as far as I know its a legal name ~FooBar
Does anyone know if the "~" does anything special?

Sorry I adjusted the code from the original post. I miss read the FooBar method.

Comment: You sure its a static method? Cause you can implement destructors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, it's a [bitwise complement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx) operator.

Comment: so a bitwise complement operation is being preformed on the return int before it is returned to the caller???   And yes the methods are static

Comment: @Buckrogerz I believe so.

Comment: Are you saying `~` is a bitwise complement operator used in this context `public static int ~FooBar() {...}`?

Comment: If it was an operator overload wouldn't it be declared static int operator~(ClassX a, ClassX b)?

Comment: @hatchet no, I have no idea what it is. I've never seen `~` in the static method declaration. I don't think it's compilable at all.

Comment: Looks like OP just changed the code.  `~` operator is no longer in the method declaration.

Comment: Sorry all I miss typed the method I am seeing characters where there are none LOL.  I adjusted the original post.

Comment: Ok, with that edit by the OP, yes, `~` is the bitwise complement operator.

Answer (score 2):

As said above, it's a bitwise operator that reverses each bit.

The `FooBar` method returns an int. Behind the scenes it returns 32 bits that will look something like:

1110000001100..... // 32 chars.
Performing `~` on that int will return 0001111110011.....

Another example:

```
~(101) = 010
~(000) = 111
```

Comment: +1 for clarification, but "it returns 32 bytes" Bytes? Really?

Comment: I meant bits and it was easy to understand that even though I wrote "bytes" by mistake.